# Left side menu on Android app always visible

Tags: android, menu, master-detail

I need to develop a fixed left side menu for an Android app that will only be used maximized on Chromebooks. What would be the best strategy in order to create a left side menu that is always visible and expanded (that is, that does not open/close or overlay the content in a drawer), something like the Google Play app has in the image? On the right hand side the app should load one fragment or another depending on the menu item selected. Do I need to develop a custom layout and implement the master/detail logic myself, or is there there some standard flow/mechanism I should rather use or adapt for this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There are design standard and a [simple implementation](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android#standard-navigation-drawer) is present in [material Drawer](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer#behavior) - you can look into it to get a better idea